# Laravel Queue job holding web service response

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen

I have implemented queue jobs in my lumen v5.6 projecs. For queue jobs i am using database driver. But the problem is that when I dispatch job and put sleep method for 15 seconds in job handle() method then job api response hold for 15 second untile the whole job is fired. But I have to sent back api response immediatly as I dispatch job in background.

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Helpers\NotificationProcess;

class SendPushNotification extends Job {

```
protected $queueData;
protected $activity;
protected $activity_user;
protected $post;
protected $mentions;
protected $noti;
protected $mention_activities;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($data) {
    \Log::info("Queue Start Time:: " . microtime());
    $this->queueData = $data;
    $this->activity = $data['activity'];
    $this->activity_user = $data['user'];
    $this->post = $data['post'];
    $this->mentions = $data['mentions'];
    $this->mention_activities = $data['mention_activities'];
    $this->noti = new NotificationProcess();
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle() {
    try {
        \Log::info("wait for 15 seconds");
        sleep(15);
        $receiver = \App\Models\DeviceToken::getDeviceTokensByUsers([$this->post->user_id], $this->activity_user->id, $this->activity['domain']);
        if (!$receiver->isEmpty() && !empty($this->activity))
            $this->noti->sendCommentPushNotification($this->activity, $receiver[0]->toArray(), $this->activity_user);
        if (!empty($this->mentions)) {
            $receivers = \App\Models\DeviceToken::getDeviceTokensByUsers($this->mentions, $this->activity_user->id, 'M');
            if (!$receivers->isEmpty() && !empty($this->mention_activities))
                $this->noti->sendMentionPushNotifications($this->mention_activities, $receivers->toArray(), $this->activity_user);
        }
        \Log::info("==== Notifications sent ===");
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
         \Log::info("Exception::".$ex->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Now I just want to send back response immediatly to api as I dispatch job for background process it should not hold the response of api.

Note: One job can be processed in 2 min but it should not effect the response of api

Comment: `handle()` method is being executed by the worker and not by the dispatch process. Maybe you are dispatching on the `sync` connection?

Comment: the job should implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#generating-job-classes

Comment: How are you running your queue workers? Can you also show your QUEUE_DRIVER in your .env file

Comment: before dispatch a job u must send api response and in background u run job and send notification that is a best idea(but u first send notification and then response api that is not a good away) for my opinion ..